# Ajax just opens PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form I am trying to submit via ajax from PHPAcademy's tutorial found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrycH6F-ksY)

Basically the form needs to submit via ajax, simple enough. But when I try do that, it just opens the PHP file in the browser. PLEASE HELP!

here is the ajax code:

```
$('form.login_settings').submit(function(){

var that = $(this),
    url = '../login_settings_submit.php',
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
    var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});

return false;
});
```

I have tried using `e.preventDefault();` but with no luck

I have also tried changing the initial function from

`$('form.login_settings').submit(function(){`

to

`$('form.login_settings').on('submit', function(){`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you do this `.find('[name]')` you might as well use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: make sure your are running this request through wamp,xamp, lamp or mamp server, and also they are running

Comment: It is running through wamp server. I know I can use serialize, but the tutorial showed me .find, the code works outside of the file (ie: another contact form), but not here?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but I faced it once: the PHP file you're requesting begins with `<?` or `<?php` ? Because the configuration of `short_open_tag at php.ini` may make the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy friend:

**Java Script Code:**

```
$(function() {
        $('form.login_settings').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var that = $(this),   
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = that.serialize()    
            $.ajax({
                type: type,
                url: '../login_settings_submit.php',
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

use jQuery **.serialize** method to parametrize form data and write code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//
}); or

$(function(){
//
});
```

and if you wanna check ajax error then you can use

```
,error : function(jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connected.\nPlease verify your network connection.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
        alert('The requested page not found. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
    } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
}
```

after success method. It's good to check ajax error always when you are in production.